# How can I temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, django, django-models

Is it possible to temporarily disable constraints in MySQL?

I have two Django models, each with a foreign key to the other one. Deleting instances of a model returns an error because of the foreign key constraint:

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM myapp_item WHERE n = %s", n)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()  #a foreign key constraint fails here

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM myapp_style WHERE n = %s", n)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

Is it possible to temporarily disable constraints and delete anyway?

Comment: Either I don't get what you want to do, or what you are trying to do is **very, very, very ugly**. Even if you can do it, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Dropping and reapplying an FK _is_ changing your db. You're trying to defy the very constraints that allow the system to see some sense, it has no regard that an FK could be a temporary thing, and if it did know, it would panic.

Comment: Its strange what you trying to do. But which database are you using?

Comment: @andrefsp: I'm using MySQL. I'll edit my question to add that.

Comment: what if, instead of disabling your constraint, you permanently modified it to `ON DELETE SET NULL`? That would accomplish a similar thing and you wouldn't have to turn key checking on and off.

Comment: @dnagirl: that would be better, indeed. How can I do that?

Comment: You should do what @dnagirl its telling you to do. Its way more reasonable and its the way to ensure you don't mess in a really nasty way with your data. Playing with it like what you want to do might lead you to serious integrity and consistency problems.

Comment: @Dariusz I do it all the time resetting certain tables in my test data db, without regenerating the whole thing. Not sure why it's do bad

Answer (score 1770, accepted):

Try `DISABLE KEYS` or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Make sure to

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

after.

Comment: is this something that is set for mysql as a whole or just that session?

Comment: I believe it is per session.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/291100/with-mysql-how-long-does-an-alter-table-disable-keys-statement-last#comment820481_291100 , Also note that you [**cannot** `disable keys`](http://serverfault.com/questions/234893/how-to-disable-keys-in-mysql-innodb/234901#comment820478_234901) for Innodb

Comment: Can I just disable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS for a single table?

Comment: @Pacerier From reading that, it appears you can, but only for a single session.

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` is not working for me. Is this working from newer version of mysql.

Comment: To clarify @Pacerier's comment: For Innodb, you cannot `DISABLE KEYS`. But you *can* accomplish what is requested in this question, using the other command shown: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` (I thought at first he was saying there was no way to accomplish this.)

Comment: @MusaddiqKhan - Yes: [MySQL 8 foreign_key_checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks). As mentioned in comments above, this is only for the current session/connection. If you still can't get it to work, *post a new question*, with good detail about what you tried, and what happened - error message?

Comment: A word of caution: MySQL doesn't revalidate the foreign keys when you reactivate the checks. This can cause serious referential errors.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer, everytime I came back here.

Answer (score 191):

To turn off foreign key constraint globally, do the following:

```
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and remember to set it back when you are done

```
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

WARNING: You should only do this when you are doing single user mode maintenance.  As it might resulted in data inconsistency.  For example, it will be very helpful when you are uploading large amount of data  using a mysqldump output.

Comment: this is what I needed to know, so its not great practice, but this guys answer should be scoring higher...

Comment: This worked for me after trying the 'best answer' didn't work for me. Perhaps an explanation of the difference could be added.

Comment: @hexnet The difference is that just `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` just changes the value for the _current connection_, while `SET GLOBAL ..` changes the value for _all connections_, including future connections. If you just do `SET FOREIGN..` in one window, then try to apply the statement in a different window (over a different connection), the value has not changed there. With `GLOBAL`, the same variable has the same value for both connections.

Comment: The only thing that could help me when playing back a larger dump (6+ GB)
<3

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  When I try, I see:`ERROR 1228 (HY000): Variable 'foreign_key_checks' is a SESSION variable and can't be used with SET GLOBAL`

Comment: Try UPPERCASE @MikeB

Comment: @berniey no luck.  It's alright though. I used `alter` statements to temporarily disable the foreign key constraints.

Comment: @MikeB, I think it has to do with the tool that you use to issue the command (it works with `myqsl` command line tool). I've been using the command on v5.5 and 5.6 and it works fine. Document suggested ut even works on v5.7. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html. Also, case doesn't matter (pardon on my earlier suggestion)

Comment: Would like to note that if you connect to MySQL that has foreign key checks enabled prior to issuing the global query, that the current session state for foreign key checks is preserved. i.e. `SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;` will return `1` until you reconnect to start a new session

Comment: this doesn't work for me (mysql 5.7).  However the accepted answer "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" does work.

Answer (score 78):

I normally only disable foreign key constraints when I want to truncate a table, and since I keep coming back to this answer this is for future me:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE table;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 28):

Instead of disabling your constraint, permanently modify it to ON DELETE SET NULL. That will accomplish a similar thing and you wouldn't have to turn key checking on and off. Like so:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename1 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name1; //get rid of current constraints
ALTER TABLE tablename2 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name2;

ALTER TABLE tablename1 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (table2_id) 
        REFERENCES table2(id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL  //add back constraint

ALTER TABLE tablename2 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) 
        REFERENCES table1(id)
        ON DELETE SET NULL //add back other constraint
```

Have a read of this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) and this (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Beware alterting table can take a long time, better to set the server global for `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to 0 and put it back once the dirty work is done. Besides it might lock for writing your tables.

Comment: Won't that break the reference when altering the remote column type? (It seems my client renames a modified temp table to the original table name.)

Answer (score 28):

To turn off the foreign key constraint globally:

```
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

And for the active foreign key constraint:

```
SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of an [existing, older answer from @berniey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24602164)

Answer (score 13):

A very simple solution with [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin):

- In your table, go to the <kbd>SQL</kbd> tab
- After you edit the SQL command that you want to run, there is a check box next to <kbd>GO</kbd>, named '*Enable foreign key checks'* .
- **Uncheck this check box and run your SQL**. It will be automatically rechecked after executing.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed solution `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; ..... SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;` didn't work for me in PHPMyAdmin because I forgot to uncheck the 'Enable foreign key checks' checkbox. In PHPMyAdmin you can skip these SET commands and just uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 13):

For me just `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` wasn't enough.
I was still having a `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`.

I had to add `ALTER TABLE myTable DISABLE KEYS;`.

So:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE myTable DISABLE KEYS;
DELETE FROM myTable;
ALTER TABLE myTable ENABLE KEYS;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: FYI, mySQL 5.7 throws warning, InnoDB engine doesn't have this option when running DISABLE KEYS command.

Comment: this did work, without the alter table it also didn't work for me

Comment: This solved my issue! thank you very much for this answer!

Answer (score 5):

In [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) you can select multiple rows and can then click the delete action. You'll enter a screen which lists the delete queries. It looks like this:

[image]

Please uncheck the "Enable foreign key checks" checkbox, and click on <kbd>Yes</kbd> to execute them.

This will enable you to delete rows even if there is an ON DELETE restriction constraint.

Answer (score 3):

If the key field is nullable, then you can also set the value to null before attempting to delete it:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE myapp_item SET myapp_style_id = NULL WHERE n = %s", n)
transaction.commit_unless_managed() 

cursor.execute("UPDATE myapp_style SET myapp_item_id = NULL WHERE n = %s", n)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM myapp_item WHERE n = %s", n)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()

cursor.execute("DELETE FROM myapp_style WHERE n = %s", n)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good idea to set a foreign key constraint to 0, because if you do, your database would not ensure it is not violating referential integrity.  This could lead to inaccurate, misleading, or incomplete data.

You make a foreign key for a reason:  because all the values in the child column shall be the same as a value in the parent column.  If there are no foreign key constraints, a child row can have a value that is not in the parent row, which would lead to inaccurate data.

For instance, let's say you have a website for students to login and every student must register for an account as a user.  You have one table for user ids, with user id as a primary key; and another table for student accounts, with student id as a column.  Since every student must have a user id, it would make sense to make the student id from the student accounts table a foreign key that references the primary key user id in the user ids table.  If there are no foreign key checks, a student could end up having a student id and no user id, which means a student can get an account without being a user, which is wrong.

Imagine if it happens to a large amount of data.  That's why you need the foreign key check.

It's best to figure out what is causing the error.  Most likely, you are trying to delete from a parent row without deleting from a child row. Try deleting from the child row before deleting from the parent row.

Comment: True, there's always a trade-off.

Comment: No one is saying to run it like this forever. You turn off constraints, bulk load some data, and flip it back on. No big deal, people do it all the time.

Comment: it is necessary for bulk imports, for performance at least, it is very common. also sometimes you just need the data to be restored, then you can make your checks.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Note, his question is how to do this temporarily.  This is required when doing certain maintenance and data imports. The caveat of course is that your import scripts become responsible for data integrity.  Then, later when the indexes and constraints are turned back on, the db will tell you if something is broken.

Comment: have you ever used phpMyAdmin?

Comment: There are situations where this is useful.

Comment: Example:

I have a table with a self-referential foreign key. The two fields are main_character_id and character_id. Each character_id must have at least one matching main_character_id. I generally want the foreign key constraint here, but it prevents me from deleting any main character (which would have the same value in both fields).

I could solve this by adding a main_character_id of 0 or -1 in the table that's used to allow update and deletion of other main characters, but is having false data better? Probably not.

Comment: I can not agree with you as it's not a permanent solution. I know this solution helped me on several occasions. Importing tables one by one in the order of constraints does not seem to be practical.