# is it good practice to remove the foreign key then delete records & finally set the foreign key back?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this problem. I got this following table:

```
employeeID - supervisorID - workerType
1          - 3            - 1
2          - 3            - 1
3          - NULL         - 1
```

supervisorID is actually the foreign of the primary key "employeeID". Each employee belongs to a workerType.

Now i want to delete all the `workerType=1`, so it will delete the `employeeID=1, employeeID=2 & employeeID=3`. However mysql won't allow cos it got the foreign key constraints (ie `employeeID=3`).

Also, i don't want `on delete cascade` cos I want to reject the illegal deletion (that is only manager can delete employee). If i allow `on delete cascade` then i have to build another system to control illegal deletion but that cos more energy.

I am using old mysql 5.0

is it good practice to remove the foreign key then delete records & finally set the foreign key back?

So how to delete `workerType=1` without removing the foreign key?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql

Comment: Try Rules. I don't Know mysql have or not rules. if have use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set FK values to NULL (`supervisorID` column if I understand correctly) and then delete.

Comment: the superVisorID of the supervisor is Null, didn't u see i showed in the question?

Comment: superVisorID of children (1 and 2)

Comment: u mean alter table "ON DELETE SET NULL"?

Comment: No, I mean UPDATE set supervisorID = NULL for the same records set call before DELETE

Comment: is that step is the same as "ON DELETE SET NULL" cos i tested "ON DELETE SET NULL" & it's working

Comment: ok, i got what u mean, but that like a hacking way, can "ON DELETE SET NULL" be more elegant?

Comment: may be you're reght and your approach is better. Implementation is up to you I just expressed the idea

Comment: u got 27K score so u got lot of experience, but why u say "Maybe"? is there any problem with "ON DELETE SET NULL"

Comment: I think ur approach is the same as "ON DELETE SET NULL" but u did it manually, while "ON DELETE SET NULL" do it automatically for you

Comment: @Tum: `ON DELETE SET NULL` would allow "illegal deletions", as you put it, in the same way as `ON DELETE CASCADE` would. Stanislav's approach, as I understand it, is to do the deletion in two explicit steps: first nullify the supervisors, then actually delete the rows.