# How to merge two databases, with same data, but with different PKs, without duplicated fields?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I have two mdb files.
I can also convert it to MySQL database, if necessary.

How can I merge these two different dbs to a single one?

The idea is to get all info form both dbs and merge into one, without duplicating any client.
The problem is that both bds have the same clients, and different ones, but the PKs of the clients aren't the same on them.

Every line has a unique field, I guess it can help somehow.
Any idea of how can I do that?

Comment: [This forum post](https://www.everymanhosting.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=42) might be at least a good start.

Comment: What would the result look like? What happens to data that references id = 2

Comment: What if X has more fields in than Y, but one of the columns in Y has a different value for the same column as X?

Comment: For instance say john on table client had a telephone # of 4444?

Comment: @Strawberry, I've posted the result, the id should be from the inserted row. Brian DeMilia, the most complete goes, althought I see that I haven't thought what if both has same ammount of data, but different data.

Comment: By which rule do you decide which two (or more) rows belong to the same client? Just the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a `UNION` all columns except the PKs will give you only distinct rows:

```
insert into new_table (<non-pk columns>)
select <non-pk columns> from tableA
union
select <non-pk columns> from tableB
```

Note: `union` removes duplicates.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how would I do if each client was relationed to another table, like "purchases"? Because the purchases would come duplicated too. The "purchases" table haven't a unique identifier. Only the FK from the client, but they are not the same on both bds.

Comment: it can be done, but that's a different and more complicated question - you should ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

I would run an UPDATE to populate one of the tables w/ all info available.

Assuming the first table has all names that the second table has (that there are no name values in table 2 that are not in table 1) you should be able to run the following update to make the first table complete:

```
update tclient1 t join (select name,
                               max(tel) as tel_filled,
                               max(address) as add_filled
                          from (select name, tel, address
                                  from tclient1
                                union all
                                select name, tel, address
                                  from tclient2) x
                         group by name) x on t.name = x.name
   set t.tel = x.tel_filled and t.address = x.add_filled;
```

See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e7dc/1/0

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable foreign keys (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql))
2. Update FK in the 2nd DB so make them unique, for instance:

   update Client 
     set id_client = id_client + 100000000;

   update History 
     set id_client = id_client + 100000000,
         id_history = id_history + 10000000;
3. Enable FKs to check integrity
4. Export 2nd DB as SQL-inserts and execute it in the 1st DB.

Use backups, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that assumes that `name` is the match between the two rows.  It just counts the numbers that are filled in and chooses the appropriate source.  This version uses `union all` with a comparison in the `where` using `>=` or `<`:

```
insert into client(id, name, tel, address)
   select id, name, tel, address
   from db1.client c1
   where ((id is not null) + (tel is not null) + (address is not null)) >=
          (select (id is not null) + (tel is not null) + (address is not null)
           from db2.client c2
           where c1.name = c2.name
          )
         )
    union all
    select id, name, tel, address
    from db2.client c2
    where ((id is not null) + (tel is not null) + (address is not null)) >
           (select (id is not null) + (tel is not null) + (address is not null)
            from db1.client c1
            where c2.name = c1.name
           )
          );
```

Note:  the above version assumes that `name` is in both tables (as in the example in your question) and there are no duplicates.  It can be easily modified if this isn't the case.

Comment: The id seems to be in both tables, but it's not the same, 1 and 2 in the example.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I made the necessary changes to the answer.