# MySql ignore foreign key error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table with lots of data. PK from that table is referenced in 7 other tables (each one of them also holds a lot of data). Now, since there was never any FK between main table and other 7 tables, i have to find a way to remove all rows from main table that's not referenced by any other row in any of those 7 other tables.
This is what i'm thinking of (all solutions should be implemented using stored procedures):

**0)** "delete from main table where id not in (select .. table 1) and not in (select..table2)...table 7" is out of the question, it would take forever to complete.

**1)** create a stored procedure that will make distinct, comma separated, set of used ids in all 7 tables and remove from the main table those ids not present in any set.

**2)** Make a "restrict" FK in every of those 7 tables and perform "Delete from main_table".

Solution No2 sounds best to me but i have a problem - i don't know how to tell mysql "delete from main table BUT skip rows which throw FK exception" :\
"Delete ignore" can't be used because it will stop removal as soon as it bumps upon row that throws FK error.

So, i have to ask you: is there a way for me to create "restrict" FK on each of those 7 tables and run "delete from main_table" with some option that will simply skip over any row which throws "FK constraint" error?

Answer (score 3):

You could use some of the resources available here:

[How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql)

http://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/

In brief, you can disable a foreign key constraint or drop it:

`ALTER TABLE table1 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name1; //get rid of current constraints`
`ALTER TABLE table2 DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name2;`

OR

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; //before your delete`

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; //after your delete`

Comment: I checked those links. Now i'm a bit confused :) I think i NEED FK, why should i disable it's check? My idea is to use FK check in order to know which row is being referenced and which isn't. The problem is that i need to keep some (unknown) amount of data in the  "main_table". I don't have problems with foreign keys because currently i don't have any :)