# MySQL is giving me an error about a table that doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problem with an error my MySQL database is giving me. Error: 1833. I cannot alter anything about a primary key on a table because mysql states:" Cannot change column 'idSubject: used in a foreign key constraint 'idSubject1' of table ''buntunovav1.semester1marks' and the problem with that error is that semester1marks is an old table I deleted a long time ago. It doesn't exist. When I show all tables, it doesn't exist. When I try to drop the table, MySQL itself states, that the table doesn't exist in the database. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct database?

Comment: `show databases;`   `use dbname;`  `show tables;`

Comment: @Barmar I'm very sure. In fact, there isn't a schema with that table.

Comment: You should probably ask for this question to be migrated to dba.stackexchange.com. They're more likely to know how to fix a database schema problem like this.

Comment: @Drew I did that, but like I said, I'm very sure the table doesn't exist in any schema. Especially in the relevant one.

Comment: so somehow it has that FK reference to a table that does not exist

Comment: so you could create a new table, dump your data into it, delete the old table, rename the new one, assuming you can delete the old one without anything forbidding it (FK's)

Comment: @Drew.... I cannot drop a table that has a column referenced in another table, well, in this case... A table that doesn't exist.

Comment: copy the data to the new table. pretend the old table doesn't exist (abandon all references to it), like the 3rd mystery table ! Isolate and ignore, that's my motto

Comment: @Barmar how do I ask for that?

Comment: @SelloNyama Click on the "Flag" link.

Comment: Try turning off foreign key checks, altering the table, then turning them back on. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql