# Delete duplicates in mySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write my first mySQL query. I need to delete rows if they have the same article-number field. I wrote this query:

```
    SELECT
    article_number, COUNT(*)
FROM
    article_numbers
GROUP BY
    article_number
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

It shows me all the rows that are duplicate. But how can I delete all but 1 for each duplicate?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried this query:

```
delete article_numbers from article_numbers inner join 
    (select  article_number
     from article_numbers 
     group by article_number
     having count(1) > 1) as duplicates
   on (duplicates.article_number = article_numbers.article_number)
```

but it gives me this error:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`api`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_article_number_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`article_number_id`) REFERENCES `article_numbers` (`id`))

EDIT 2:

I disabled the foreign key temporarily, and now my delete query works. But how can I modify it that one of the duplicate rows is not deleted?

Comment: You have to distinguish one row from it's duplicate somehow. (Any id column, or timestamp? What's the primary key?)

Comment: Also, don't tag products not involved. Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete duplicate rows in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: What all are the columns in the table `article_numbers`?

Comment: Each row has an ID field with a different ID for each row.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, it is mysql

Comment: Another question is, do you simply want to remove duplicates now, or do you also want to prevent them from ever happening?

Comment: Edited my question to include query I tried

Comment: Your *first* SQL query is to delete rows.  That seems curious . . . how did the data get there in the first place?  ;)

Comment: @Chris I only want to delete them now

Comment: Just add this in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I imported it from a CSV

Comment: asking again `What all are the columns in the table article_numbers?`

Comment: @Ullas there are the following columns: id, article_number, created_at, updated_at, price

Comment: Did you try to disable the foreign key temporarily? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql

Comment: @xpy thanks, now my delete query works. How can I modify it though, that it keeps one of the duplicates, meaning if there are 3 rows with the same article_number, 1 stays?

Comment: @razer I think Ullas answer will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CROSS JOIN`.

**Query**

```
delete t1
from article_numbers t1,
article_numbers t2
where t1.id > t2.id 
and t1.article_number = t2.article_number;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f102/1)

Answer (score 0):

I use a rather simple query to remove dupes:

```
;WITH DEDUPE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY article_number
        ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN
FROM article_numbers)
DELETE FROM DEDUPE
WHERE RN != 1
```

Comment: OP needs `mysql` query

Comment: This wasn't apparent at the time of my posting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete c
from (select *,rank() over(order by article_number) as r  from article_numbers )c
where c.r!=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete a row if same article_number but higher id exists:

```
delete from article_numbers t1
where exists (select 1 from article_numbers t2
              where t2.article_number = t1.article_number
                and t2.id > t1.id)
```

Core ANSI SQL, so I suppose it works with both MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't1
where exists (select 1 from article_numbers t2
              where t2.article' at line 1`

Comment: Sorry, apparently MySQL doesn't support it. (Conforms to Core SQL-2003.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help:

```
    WITH tblTemp as
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY Name,Department ORDER BY Name)
       As RowNumber,* FROM <table_name>
    )
    DELETE FROM tblTemp where RowNumber >1
```

Comment: OP needs mysql query.

Comment: oh this is for SQL Server. can be converted to MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my query and I think it works now:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
delete article_numbers from article_numbers inner join 
    (select  min(id) minid, article_number
     from article_numbers 
     group by article_number
     having count(1) > 1) as duplicates
   on (duplicates.article_number = article_numbers.article_number and duplicates.minid <> article_numbers.id)
```

But it seems very complex. I will check @Ullas method to see if it works, too.