# Restoring MySQL Database in Symfony Error 1005

Tags: mysql, doctrine, database-restore, symfony-2.8

I'm moving my Symfony app from one server to another, all is working fine but DB, I extracted the database to a bd_backup.sql file and when I try to restore the database I got this error in several tables:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'mydatabase.student' (errno: 121)
```

the method I use is though mysql console:

```
mysql> use mydatabase;
mysql> source bd_backup.sql;
```

Is there a way to solve this? greetings!

Comment: 121 = foreign key error. how did you "extract" this database file?

Comment: Old app is hosted in Heroku, I use the ClearDB backup system

Comment: well, if that dump is a full db, and doesn't have the standard prefix commands that mysqldump inserts for you (like disabling foreign key checks), you probably have the script trying to drop a table while keys are still enabled, and you're not being allowed to create orphan records.

Comment: How can I fix that? (sorry my noob knowledge)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks but didn't worked, still the same error