# It's not possible to remove indexes

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

The following create statement shows the current structure of one of my MariaDB tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `councilor` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `council` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `role` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'member' COLLATE 'utf8_persian_ci',
    `cDate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `uDate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `startDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `endDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `responsibility` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_persian_ci',
    `details` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_persian_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `userId_councilId` (`user`, `council`),
    INDEX `council_user_council_foreign` (`council`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_persian_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
```

I need to remove the unique index, however trying to delete either of two keys fails.

```
ALTER TABLE `councilor`
    DROP INDEX `userId_councilId`;
```

/* SQL Error (1553): Cannot drop index 'userId_councilId': needed in a foreign key constraint */

```
ALTER TABLE `councilor`
    DROP INDEX `council_user_council_foreign`;
```

/* SQL Error (1553): Cannot drop index 'council_user_council_foreign': needed in a foreign key constraint */

Removing all table's rows does not help as well. However, if a new table is created by the above script the issue will not occur.

Comment: you last updated made whole question senseless. Pls review whole question  and updated it properly

Comment: The Following Structure you posted is wrong

Comment: Try the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql

Answer (score 7):

> 18:18:46  ALTER TABLE location DROP INDEX unique_name_to_supplier Error
>   Code: 1553. Cannot drop index 'unique_name_to_supplier': needed in a
>   foreign key constraint    0.063 sec

This means you are trying to delete index that used  for FK.

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create
>   another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint.
>   index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

**So to fix is you need:**

1.Get rid of FK

2.Remove index itself

3.Create FK again

**Here are the commands:**

```
#removing FK
    ALTER TABLE `location`  DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_SUPPLIER`;

#droping unique Index
    ALTER TABLE `location`  DROP INDEX `unique_name_to_supplier` ;

#creating new FK with proper Index    
    ALTER TABLE `location` 
    ADD INDEX `FK_SUPPLIER_idx` (`supplier_id` ASC);
    ALTER TABLE `location` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_SUPPLIER`
      FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`)
      REFERENCES `supplier` (`id`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

**full sql log:**

```
mysql>
mysql> CREATE TABLE supplier (
    ->  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE location (
    ->  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->  name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    ->  supplier_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE location ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SUPPLIER FOREIGN KEY FK_SUPPLIER (supplier_id)
    ->    REFERENCES supplier (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.41 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE location ADD UNIQUE INDEX unique_name_to_supplier (supplier_id,name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table location;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table
                                                                                                                                |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| location | CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_name_to_supplier` (`supplier_id`,`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SUPPLIER` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `supplier` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql>
mysql>
mysql>
mysql> ALTER TABLE `location`  DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_SUPPLIER`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> ALTER TABLE `location`  DROP INDEX `unique_name_to_supplier` ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
mysql> ALTER TABLE `location`
    -> ADD INDEX `FK_SUPPLIER_idx` (`supplier_id` ASC);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `location`
    -> ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_SUPPLIER`
    ->   FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`)
    ->   REFERENCES `supplier` (`id`)
    ->   ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ->   ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.68 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table location
    -> ;
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table
                                                                                                                                                  |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| location | CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_SUPPLIER_idx` (`supplier_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_SUPPLIER` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `supplier` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: my answer was not helpfull ?

Comment: @PHPst you are missing something because   your error says ` SQL Error (1553): Cannot drop index 'userId_councilId': needed in a foreign key constraint */`

Comment: It is my question as well!

Comment: at the moment your question doesn't make sens

Answer (score 6):

You have to drop FOREIGN KEY constraint first, then drop index and recreate FOREIGN key.

Answer (score 5):

You have to drop the foreign key constraint first, and that

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP FOREIGN KEY [Foreign_key_constraint_name];
```

and than you can drop the index