# MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE not work

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i have two table (type innoDb) why when i deleting main table row like

+note(im using arch os so my database server type is maria db)

```
DELETE FROM buildings 
WHERE
    building_no = 2;
```

relation table rows dont delete ???

```
CREATE TABLE buildings (
    building_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    building_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    building_no INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (building_no)
        REFERENCES buildings (building_no)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Are both tables of type InnoDB?

Comment: Yes both are InnoDB

Comment: Everything is fine..!! And working proper for me.

Comment: For me too. Can not be reproduced. See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82c235/1/0

Comment: guys i updated note and tag i should say database server type is maria db is cause of my problem ?

Comment: Probably not. Likeliest cause is, that you haven't double checked everything like engine type (since you didn't specify it in your create statement).

Comment: i rebuild my table with ENGINE=InnoDB;  line to end of my sql command but still not work still have the problem

Comment: see here i did some building delete

http://www.axgig.com/images/79751284206007638635.png

building rows is 0 but rooms rows not changed at all

Comment: Please check `select @@foreign_key_checks;`. If it is 0, you [disabled the checks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15501673/6248528) and the cascades cannot work.

Comment: @Solarflare
it is 0 ! where should i enable foreign key check ?

Comment: solved ! thankyou  Solarflare

Comment: See the link I added in my comment to set it back. It is enabled by default. If it keeps getting disables, you might have to find out where, but is often disables by e.g. data import scripts (that you may have run lately, are sometimes after your last server restart), so it is probably a one time thing - but keep it in mind.

Comment: @Solarflare Why don't you add it as an answer. Would upvote it, since I haven't thought about that.

Comment: Have same problem here. both tables are innodb and foreign_key_checks is 1

Comment: Mine has foreign_key_check enabled yet on delete cascade is not working!

Answer (score -1):

This syntax works for me on MySQL database but i can't see issues in your query too

```
CREATE TABLE  `rooms` (
  room_no INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  room_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  building_no INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_rooms_1` FOREIGN KEY (`building_no`) REFERENCES `buildings` 
  (`building_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

or add the constraint after table creation

```
ALTER TABLE `rooms`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_rooms_1` FOREIGN KEY (`building_no`) REFERENCES `buildings` (`building_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```