# How to disable foreign key check on database import via console?

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

I know I can import a database dump like this:

```
mysql -u {{username}} -p {{target_database}} < myDump.sql
```

e.g.

```
mysql -u root -p theDatabase < myDump.sql
```

But how to import a database with foreign key check turned off?

I searched the mysql help for helpful parameters, but I found none:

```
mysql --help | findstr "foreign"
```

Returns nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First edit your database file and put `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` at beginning and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` at the end of the database file.

This will help turn off the foreign key checks while restoring and it will also turn on the checks after restoration.

Comment: Does this work with any user or it requires some special privileges or root access?

Comment: @hypercube The foreign_key_checks system variable requires the SUPER privilege to dynamically set its global value at runtime.

The foreign_key_checks system variable does not require any special privilege to dynamically set its session value at runtime.