# How to update values of foreign key fields referencing to a parent table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am migrating a table to a new format and as part of the process, I need to delete rows and condense them into a single row. However, these old rows are being referenced by other tables.

Is there a way to automatically update the values of the foreign keys referencing the old rows to the 'id' of the newly-created row or is this only possible manually going through all the referencing tables? I am using a number (id) to identify the rows.

The only other way possible is to go through each referencing table and update the old values with multiple sub-queries OR disable foreign key checks then delete the old rows, but this wouldn't update the values in child tables.

> Error Message: SQL Error (1451): Cannot delete or update a parent row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails... (table names I can't show)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a mapping between the Old and New Ids first, and then temporary introduce a new field called *NewId* what you will populate from that mapping. Next, once you have populated all new Ids, you can simply update your primary Id from the new one and delete the *NewId* column completely.

Of course, before you start any key updates you will require to disable a foreign key constraint, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql) about how to do it.