# Is there a way to update 12000+ rows from txt file in less then 2mins?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I need to update a table with more then 12000 row using php Codeigniter and a txt file.. reading the file and the `foreach` loop are fine but when updating line by line it takes like 30 mins, I guess the problem is I'm searching by name because I have no id in the txt file...
Here is my code:

**controller:**

```
$fn = fopen($this->upload->data('full_path'),"r");

$update = true;
while(! feof($fn) && $update)  {
    $pieces = explode("|", fgets($fn));
    if(sizeof($pieces) == 9 && is_numeric(trim($pieces[1]))) {
        $update = $this->model_products->update3s($pieces);
    }
} 

fclose($fn);
```

**Model:**

```
public function update3s($product) {
    if ($product) {
        $product[2] = trim(str_replace("'","''",$product[2]));
        $product[1] = trim($product[1]);
        $product[6] = trim($product[6]);
        $product[3] = trim($product[3]);
        $sql = "UPDATE products set qty = $product[3], price_vente = $product[6]  where (name = '$product[2]')";
        echo $sql.'<br>';
        $update = $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $update;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Indexing your table can simply reduce the time

Comment: @AkshitAhuja i have a primary key (ai int) but the only thing that's unique in the txt file is the name..

Comment: Adds a unique index to the `name`, uses a parameterized request, prepares the statement before the loop

Comment: Some tips: * [Disable foreign key constraints in MySQL, temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501754/1461181)
* [Use bulk inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)
* [Use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1461181)

Comment: You can merge multiple update statements with a CASE END cluase if you update one table something like  `UPDATE table SET qty =(CASE WHEN name = 'product_1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) WHERE name IN(...)` ... Keep in mind to write/test this on "offline" data... Also using TRANSACTION can speed up multiple updates queries and not to forgot the indexing the column(s) which you use in WHERE clause of the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use transaction and add index for column `name` in database table.

```
$fn = fopen($this->upload->data('full_path'),"r");

$update = true;

$updatedCount = 0;

while(! feof($fn) && $update)  {
    $pieces = explode("|", fgets($fn));
    if(sizeof($pieces) == 9 && is_numeric(trim($pieces[1]))) {
      if ($updatedCount == 0) {
         $databaseInstance->beginTransaction();
      }
      $update = $this->model_products->update3s($pieces);
      ++$updatedCount;

      if ($updatedCount > 500) { //in one transaction update 500 rows
         $databaseInstance->commit();
         $updatedCount = 0;
      }
    }
} 

if ($updatedCount > 0) { // if we have not commited transaction 
   $databaseInstance->commit();
}

fclose($fn);
```

Answer (score 3):

Some tips

- Add index to field `name`
- Use prepared statements
- Disable the MySQL forgeign key check [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

writing sql function can do that even in much lesser time .
using feature like :

- [REPLACE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp)
- [cursors](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/)
- [SPLIT_STRING(custom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

in a mysql user defined [function](http://www.sqlexamples.info/PHP/mysql_udf1.htm)

```
CREATE FUNCTION update3s(hole_file_content LONGTEXT) RETURNS Boolean
BEGIN 
                    -----Your implementation(same logic in sql ) ------ 
END
```

then coll it just by if it is CI 3

```
$this->db->call_function('update3s', file_get_contents($this->upload->data('full_path')));
```

else

```
$this->db->query("select update3s(".file_get_contents($this->upload->data('full_path')).")");
```