# Trying to disable foreign key checks, but unsuccessful

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I am trying to temporarily disable foreign key checks, but have not been successful.

````
```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `menu_items`;
CREATE TABLE `menu_items` (
...
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```
````

It keeps telling me that I cannot delete or update a parent row. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql/29261661). Take a look -- maybe there is something there for you.

Answer (score 0):

To disable foreign key constraints when you want to truncate a table:

**Use FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

**Or you can use DISABLE KEYS:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS;
```

Comment: He tried the first one and the second one does not work for InnoDB tables.