# How do I delete specific entries wherein there are duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry I'm just using this account from my old friend, he said he wanted it to have higher reputation. lol

I have a table that looks like this and I want to delete the entries wherein the next duplicate ones based from the first_name, middle_name, and last_name, and alias columns. While keeping the first entry or the ones who have the `lowest` possible id 
[image]

Comment: Add an example to your example. It will clarify what do you want exactly.

Comment: For starting your post with "Sorry I'm just using this account from my old friend, he said he wanted it to have higher reputation. lol", i downvoted.   Also you should not post pictures for such a problem. This problem is easily explained in words, while a DDL and some example data CAN be usefull.

Comment: Ok sir , I upvote u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a self join in the `delete` statement:

```
delete t
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.first_name = t.first_name and tt.last_name = t.last_name and tt.alias = t.alias  
and tt.id < t.id;
```

or by deleting all the rows with `id`s other than the min `id`s of each combination of `first_name`, `last_name` and `alias`:

```
delete from tablename
where id not in (
  select t.minid from (
    select min(id) minid
    from tablename
    group by first_name, last_name, alias
  ) t
)
```

Comment: `Delete C1 from criminals C1 inner join criminals C2 where C1.id > c2.id and C1.first_name = C2.first_name and C1.last_name = C2.last_name and C1.alias = C2.alias;`
I used my own query for finishing this but I get
```#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mixx`.`criminal_profiles`, CONSTRAINT `criminal_infos_criminal_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`criminal_id`) REFERENCES `criminals` (`id`))```

Comment: Change `where` to `on`.

Comment: what do u mean brother ?

Comment: Your code uses `where` it should be `on` because there is a join. But now that I see all your comment there is a constraint in the table `criminal_profiles` because the column `criminal_id` references the `id` of `criminals` so you can't delete.

Comment: How do I enable them to delete

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql